# The most efficient way to initialize array member of struct?

Tags: c

I have declared the struct

```
struct wnode {
  char *word;
  int lines[MAXLINES];
  struct wnode *left;
  struct wnode *right;
};
```

and the pointer

```
struct wnode *p;
```

The pointer is passed to a function.
In that function, I first allocate memory for the pointer with malloc. Then I want to <strike>initialize the struct member **lines** to zero</strike> zero out the struct member **lines**.

An array initialization method will not work as it is interpreted as assignment:

```
p->lines[MAXLINES] = {0};
```

The compiler throws the error:

> error: expected expression before '{' token

In the end, I'm just using a for loop to zero out the **lines** array:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAXLINES; i++)
  p->lines[i] = 0;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: yes use memset for initializing

Comment: First off, the name of the member is `lines`, not `lines[]`. The `[]` is part of its **type**. Similarly, writing `p->lines[MAXLINES]` attempts to *index into* `p->lines`, and `MAXLINES` will not be a valid index for that array.

Comment: An *initializer* is part of a *declaration*, so you aren't initializing. You are assigning, and 1) you can't assign to an array, and 2) `{0}` is not a valid expression.

Comment: Re "*the most efficient way for Initialize array member of struct?*", Use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to allocate the struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays cannot be assigned to directly.  You need to either use a loop to set all fields to 0 or you can use `memset`:

```
memset(p->lines, 0, sizeof(p->lines));
```

Note that for non-char types you can only to do this to set all members to 0.  For any other value you need a loop.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the `=` operator, you can do it this way:

```
struct wnode wn, *p;
/* ........ */
wn = (struct wnode){.word = wn.word, .lines = {0,}, .left = wn.left, .right = wn.right};
*p = (struct wnode){.word = p ->word, .lines = {0,}, .left = p -> left, .right = p -> right};
```

Comment: Very interesting idea. Thanks. I will try it out.

Comment: I think this is the best approach as OP certainly does not want to initial/assign _only_ the `.lines` member, but all members.  This answer accomplishes that in one step that the compiler can optimize and realize "The most efficient way to initialize" all members 
 "of struct".

Answer (score 4):

`= {0}`  works only on initialization. You can't use it with assignment as such which is why you get the error.

You can either use a `for` loop as you said or use `memset` to zero out the array:

```
memset(p -> lines, 0, sizeof(p -> lines))
```

Comment: sizeof(p -> lines) * MAXLINES! this is incorrect size!

Comment: @Adam Already fixed that before your comment. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The only time an array variable can be initialized in this manner:

```
int someInt[MAXLINES] = {0};
```

Is during declaration.

But because this particular variable `int lines[MAXLINES];` is declared within the confines of `struct`, which does not allow members to be initialized, the opportunity is lost to that method, requiring it to be initialized after the fact, and using a different method.

The most common (and preferred) way to initialize after declaration in this case is to use:

```
//preferred
memset(p->lines, 0, sizeof(p->lines));
```

A more arduous method, and one that is seen often, sets each element to the desired value in a loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<MAXLINES;i++)
{
    p->lines[i] = 0;
}
```

As noted in comments, this method will be reduced by a good optimizing compiler to the equivalent of an `memset()` statement anyway.

Comment: short and good answer! but i think better to calculate the sizeof the array like i did, (sizeof(int)*MAXLINES).

Comment: Less preffered method (?WHY? ?BY WHO?) will be reduced by any optimizing compiler to memset.

Comment: @Adam no it is a wrong way. What if you decide to change the type to char? Then you need to change it everywhere. If you forget one change - UB. Let the compiler do the hard job for you.

Comment: @ryyker it same readable as `memset` no difference for me.

Comment: Very helpful explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**`void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n)`**

> The memset() function fills the first n bytes of the memory area
> pointed to by s with the constant byte c.
>
> The memset() function returns a pointer to the memory area s.

Although, `(sizeof(int)*MAXLINES)` and `sizeof(p->lines)` yields the same result in bytes, and both are correct **BUT**, the second option ( `sizeof(p->lines)`) is better to use, because if we decide to change the array type or the array size, we dont need to change the expression inside the szieof operator. we change in oneplace only. so we let the compiler to do the work for us!

```
#include <string.h>  /*for the memset*/
memset(p->lines, 0x0, sizeof(p->lines));
```

Comment: Well, not the `p->lines =` part.

Comment: I don't believe the assignment is correct; just doing `memset(p->lines, 0, sizeof p->lines);` would do the trick.

Comment: sorry my bad. guys i was the first to answer. dont forget please :-)

Comment: Though *use* of `p->lines` decays to a pointer, it's still an array, so `sizeof(p->lines)` gets the whole size and is the best way to do this.

Comment: @SteveFriedl - can you explain please why its better to use sizeof(p->lines) than sizeof(int)*MAXLINES. thanks.

Comment: `sizeof(int)*MAXLINES` it is not very good way. Very error prone if you want to change the type. Always use **objects** in `sizeof` instead of types

Comment: Hi @Adam - functionally they yield the same value, but what happens if the struct changes it to `int lines[MAXLINES+1]` or changes from `int` to `long` or the like?  Then you have to change it in two places, but by deriving the size from the object, you don't have to think about it.

Comment: "why its better to use sizeof(p->lines)" --> It is easier to review and maintain.

Comment: thank you all. i am updating my answer. really appreciate your comments. i have learned something new today :-) . i am happy.

Comment: `szieof` -> `sizeof` typo :)

Comment: Note: `()` not  needed in `sizeof(p->lines)`.   `sizeof p->lines` is fine.  As with such style issues, code yto your group's guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration of a pointer

```
struct wnode *p;
```

either zero-initializes the pointer `p` if the pointer has static storage duration or leaves the pointer uninitialized if the pointer has automatic storage duration, So applying the operator -> to the pointer invokes undefined behavior because the pointer does not point to a valid object.

If to assume that the pointer points to a valid object like for example

```
struct wnode w;

struct wnode *p = &w;
```

then within the function you can initialize the data member lines of the object w using the standard C function `memset`. For example

```
memset( p->lines, 0, MAXLINES * sizeof( int ) );
```

You may not write in the function just

```
p->lines = {0};
```

because the pointed object is already created and such an initialization is allowed in a declaration of an array. And moreover arrays do not have the assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of initialization can only be done on declaration. Notice that in `p->lines[MAXLINES] = {0};` the expression `p->lines[MAXLINES]` means *the integer one past the end of p->lines*.
You could write `p->lines[MAXLINES] = 0;`. Not correct, but would compile.

You don't have the concept of *array* any more. You either have `p->lines`, which is a pointer to int, or `p->lines[index]`, which is an int.

Yes, you have the allocated space, but that's all. `memset` will do the trick.

By the way, I hope your function (or the caller) do allocate the wnode  element...

Answer (score 1):

`{0}` works only in initialization, not in assignment.
Since you can't initialize a pointer target, only assign to it, you can work around the problem by assigning a just-initialized compound literal.

Compilers will usually optimize the compound literal out and assign directly to the target.

`{0}` initialization of a largish array will frequently compile to a call to `memset` or equivalent assembly, so another option is to call `memset` directly on `p->lines` manually.

Example:

```
#define MAXLINES 100
struct wnode {
  char *word;
  int lines[MAXLINES];
  struct wnode *left;
  struct wnode *right;
};

//(hopefully) elided compound literal
void wnode__init(struct wnode *X)
{
    *X = (struct wnode){"foo",{0},X,X};
}

//explicit memset
#include <string.h>
void wnode__init2(struct wnode *X)
{
    X->word = "foo";
    memset(X->lines,0,sizeof(X->lines));
    X->left = X;
    X->right = X;
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TMgGqV

Answer (score 0):

@[ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)'s comment to the original question needs to be an answer.

Use `calloc()` rather than `malloc()`

```
struct wnode *p;

// presumably you have N as the number of elements and
p = malloc(N * sizeof *p);
// replace with
//p = calloc(N, sizeof *p);
```